# addition of integer to char

Tags: c++, string, ascii

can someone explain what is happening here with ascii values in first one addition of char to int is working fine

But in second one not working
can you Please explain how it works?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){ 
    string str="1234";

    str[0]=str[0]+1;    //working fine 
    cout<<str<<endl;
    str[1]=str[1]+'c';   //printing some new character at 1 position
    cout<<str<<endl;
}
```

I am n

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What were you expecting to happen and what actually happened?

Comment: What does "working fine" mean? I'm not sure I see the point of doing any kind of arithmetic to character codes (except treating them as binary and applying an encryption algorithm, resulting in binary). Text is very complicated data. Is this some sort of programming exercise?

Answer (score 1):

`str[1] = str[1] + 'c'` does `'2' + 'c'`, which is not the same as `2 + 'c'`.

In ascii, `'2'` is `50`, whereas `'c'` is `99`.

Its sum is `149` which is not in the range of ascii (0-127) so the displayed character depends of the extended ASCII you use (possibly `ò`).

If you want to have `2 + 'c'`, you have to do `str[1] = str[1] + 'c' - '0'` in your case.

Comment: Might be worth adding that the semantic equivalent to what they probably wanted was `str[1] = (str[1] - '0') + 'c';`

Comment: Note that OP's encoding isn't technically guaranteed to be (extended) ASCII although that may be likely.

Comment: @eerorika: OP wrote ascii and tag it, and I doubt OP uses EBCDIC :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 whoops :) Likelihood of OP using ASCII is even higher knowing that, but let's just say for other visitors that it isn't the only encoding.